# Android kotlin - get simple string from url

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I can't believe it isn't answered anywere!

How can I get like the IP from `https://ipinfo.io/ip` which would be nothing but a simple string?

This is what I've tried:

```
    var soo = "meh"

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://ipinfo.io/ip",
            object : Response.Listener<String> {
                override fun onResponse(response: String) {
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string
                    soo = response
                    Log.d("letsSee", soo) // THIS WAS CALLED SECOND: the ip
                }
            }, object : Response.ErrorListener {
        override fun onErrorResponse(error: VolleyError) {
            soo = "error occurred"
        }
    })
    queue.add(stringRequest)

    Log.d("letsSee", soo) // THIS WAS CALLED FIRST: "meh"
```

Comment: Maybe `onResponse(...)` is not called? Update your `soo = "error occurred"` in `onErrorResponse(..)` to see if the request fails. PS: Do you have internet permission added?

Comment: Nope neither onResponse nor onErrorResponse is called, I think it's because of "queue" but how to fix this? I also rather have a proper method to get String from url instead of this

Comment: The last log statement: `Log.d("letsSee", soo) // THIS WAS CALLED FIRST: "meh"` will always be called first and print "meh", that is fine, because you are executing an asynchronous HTTP request that runs on a separate thread. So as soon as the request is put in the queue, your application does not wait for an answer, but rather continues to execute so it meets the `Log` statement and prints `meh` because the variable `soo` was not updated yet. If you have to do anything with the IP result, like displaying it in a `TextView`, then it has to be done from `onResponse(..)`

Comment: This is what I thought and it's pretty obvious but how to FIX this? I NEED it to be NON async

Comment: No you don't, if you try to perform a non async http request your app will crash with `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Just perform any logic you have in `onResponse(...)`, or in a separate method but that is called from `onResponse(...)`.

Comment: well ok when there isn't a proper way like in php/js ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android all network calls are async and doesn't execute on main thread,
Volley follows the same methodology and makes it's network call async,
So in your code "Log.d("letsSee", soo)" statement won't wait for Volley to execute network call instead it will get executed

So you have to create callback interface like this

```
interface ApiResponse{
fun onSuccess(response:String)
fun onError()
```

}

and then make one function like this

```
fun getMyIp(apiResponse: ApiResponse) {
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "https://ipinfo.io/ip"

    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                apiResponse.onSuccess(response)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                apiResponse.onError()
            }
    )

    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

and call this getMyIp() function like this

```
getMyIp(object :ApiResponse{
        override fun onSuccess(response: String) {
            Log.d("SSB Log", response)
        }

        override fun onError() {
            Log.d("SSB Log", "Error")
        }

    })
```

ou can also implement ApiResponse interface at class level

Comment: For system limitation and benefits as like 2 side of coin, so we have to follow them when we are a software developer :)

Answer (score 1):

this is working

```
    var soo = "meh"

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://ipinfo.io/ip",
            com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                soo = response
                Log.d("see again", soo)
            }, com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener {
        // didn't work
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest)

    Log.d("letsSee", soo)
```

Comment: unsolved reference: body. I also would rather see a complete another way because this one seems weird anyway

Comment: yeah i updated my answer at same time as your question, you were calling Log at wrong time

Comment: no this is identical to that before, the log at the botton is called bvefore response in the method

Comment: yeah, i kept the bottom log just for testing purpose, of course you can ignore it or delete it, the one with "see again" label is correct